# C pointer mistakes in my understanding of the problem

Tags: c

The output result after execution is______

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{  char str[]="xyz",*ps=str;
   while(*ps) 
       ps++;
   for(ps--;ps-str>=0;ps--)
       puts(ps);
   return 0;
}
```

The right answer is  
`z`
`yz`
`xyz`

My logic is
After `while(*ps) ps++;`   `*ps`represents `" "` the last element of the array
When execute code`for(ps--;ps-str>=0;ps--)puts(ps);`,`*ps` go back two positions everytime.
So I think t should be 
`z`
`xyz`

Comment: _"After `while(*ps) ps++;` `*ps` represents `" "`"_ - no. `*ps` is then `'\0'`. Your program is already outputting the strings you claim to be the right answer, so what are you trying to change?

Comment: This program has undefined behavior, and no particular output is guaranteed. Specifically, decrementin `ps` to before `str` is undefined behavior.

Comment: The loop only moves by one element at a time. I am dubious about whether it strictly conforms to the language standard though. You are running your pointer off the _beginning_ of the array and then comparing that against the array address. This is undefined behavior. You're only allowed to do that when you run off the other end, as far as I know anyway. And only one-past-the-end. at that.

Comment: A plausible optimization the compiler might make is to note that `ps-str>=0` `is always true (since `ps` can never legally be smaller than `str`) so omit that test from the for loop.

Comment: What is the code trying to do in pseudocode terms? Don't describe with variables.

Answer (score 2):

Probably closer to what you want:

```
int main()
{  
   char str[]="xyz";
   size_t length = sizeof(str)-1;
   // size_t length = strlen(str); // safer version of above.
 
   for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
       char* ps = str+length-i-1;
       puts(ps);
   }
}
```

Comment: May be worth explaining why the safer version is safer and provide a bit of learning on the use of `sizeof()` in the scope where the array was declared of it called in a function operating on a pointer passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

> *"After `while(*ps) ps++;` `*ps` represents `" "`"*

No, `*ps` is then `'\0'`.

> When execute code `for(ps--;ps-str>=0;ps--)puts(ps);`, `*ps` go back two positions everytime

No, it does not. It starts by going back one step, then in each iteration it only goes back one step. It's the same as doing this:

```c
{
    ps--;                 // for(ps--; ...; ...)
    while(ps-str >= 0) {  // for(...; ps-str >= 0; ...)
        puts(ps);
        ps--;             // for(...; ...; ps--)
    }
}
```

`ps-str>=0` is not a good test though. If you step `ps` "behind" the start of `str` the comparison is invalid.

A safe version could simply be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[] = "xyz", *ps = str;
    
    while (*ps) ps++;
    
    while (ps != str) {
        --ps;
        puts(ps);
    }
}
```